# JQuery datepicker with a line break between day and month

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to add a `<br>` or something in the input between the day and the month, using JQuery datepicker.

I have the code below:

```
jQuery('#checkin').datepicker({
        showAnim: "drop",
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        minDate: "-0D",

    });

    jQuery('#checkout').datepicker({
        showAnim: "drop",
        dateFormat: "dd/MM/yy",
        minDate: "-0D",
        beforeShow: function () {
            var a = jQuery("#checkin").datepicker('getDate');
            if (a) return {
                minDate: a
            }
        }
    });
```

To be more specific the final input is like this:
[image]

and I want to have something like this:
[image]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only the datepicker I think it's not possible.
But you can use a bit of Javascript to do it ;-)

Check this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#date').on('click', function() {
    $('#thedate').datepicker('show');
  });

  $('#thedate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'd M yy',
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
      var arr = selectedDate.split(" ");
      $('#date').html("<span class='date_day'>" + arr[0] + "</span><span class='date_month'>" + arr[1] + "</span> <span class='date_year'>" + arr[2] + "</span>");
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#date {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif
}

#date span.date_day {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
}

#date span.date_month,
#date span.date_year {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id='date'>
  Select a date
</div>
<input id="thedate" type="hidden" /><br />
```

Comment: Excellent solution and thanks a lot! Could this also work for a datepicker date range?  https://jsfiddle.net/kw4oya72

Comment: Of course, we only added a bit of CSS and a span to the default fields the datepicker fills with the date. The datepicker range has to and from and two change methods. Check this example: https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/date-range.html

Comment: Yes, but the input value doesn't change on date range. Could it?

Comment: Check the example, there are two inputs, and the methods are divided for each field. So this code should apply to a range doing the same change method in both fields.